# How to read the content of a python package?

Tags: python, package

I recently installed `inflect.py` package to use the `ordinal()` function which formats a number as "1st" as apposed to "1", or "one". I'm new to programming and had been attempting to write a function to do this myself, but eventually found a link to this package as a solution to the problem.

I want to know if there is a way to view the code of the `inflect.py` package so i can try to understand how `ordinal()` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is source code repository for `inflect` package - https://github.com/jazzband/inflect - you could check source code and functions implementation here...